# "Отказаться от" before a clause

Tags: глаголы, предлоги

I know that the verb **отказаться** requires the preposition **от** before mentioning the thing to be refused.

If the following word is a noun, then no problem. The noun declines into the genitive.

> *They refused the silver medal.* **Они отказались от серебряной медали.**

But, what if we put a clause after **от** rather than just a noun?

> *They refused to receive the silver medal.* Они отказались **от того, чтобы** получить серебряную медаль.

Does it work this way?

Comment: this is correct but too wordy, more pertinent to vernacular, one can also say ***Они отказались от получения серебряной медали*** which is an equivalent of ***They refused receiving/receipt***

Comment: and also ***отказались получать*** just like in another question ***рискует потерять***, subordinate clause makes more sense when there's a need to use a verb with a different subject

Comment: Then, whenever a verb is typically followed by a preposition + declined noun, or just a declined noun, if the first verb is followed by a second verb instead, we just need to add the second verb in the infinitive with no preposition?

Comment: this only applies to verbs which can have modal function (those in the 1st position), which describe act or a state affecting other act, i believe their repertoire largely matches that of English, in English too we can say ***refused to accept***, ***risks to lose***, i tried to look for a list of such verbs but have been unsuccessful so far, some examples are *бояться, лениться, надеяться, нравиться, сомневаться (special case), мечтать, сесть, встать, лечь, пойти, остаться, предлагать, отговаривать, (раз)убеждать*

Comment: it seems that most of them are intransitive or transitive able to also accept indirect object

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're absolutely right with the Russian translation, only *to receive the silver medal* is not a clause, it's an infinitive phrase. A clause should have a subject of its own. Anyway, with a real clause it will work just the same way, with **от того, чтобы**, for example:

> Они отказались **от того, чтобы** *он* вручил им серебряную медаль. (They refused that he should give them the silver medal.)